# Install Ubuntu in a PC with pre-installed Windows using a new drive (still being able to put the old drive with Windows back)

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

I have a laptop (say, `Laptop1`) with an hard drive (say `hdd1`) on which Windows 8.1 is pre-installed (with UEFI, I'm told) -- and there is a dual boot with *Kubuntu* 15.04.

I also have another drive (`ssd1`), with currently *Windows* 7  installed (but not pre-installed), which I previously used on another PC.

Now, I want to replace `hdd1` with `sdd1` into `Laptop1`, wipe everything on `ssd1` and install *Xubuntu* 15.04.

However, I also want to be able to put `hdd1` back into `Laptop1` at any time and be able to use the pre-installed *Windows* 8.1 without any trouble (that is, **as if nothing had happened**).

> How do I need to proceed when installing *Xubuntu* on `ssd1`?

---

Thanks for your help.

Comment: UEFI seems to forget entries when a drive is disconnected. Not sure if after a couple reboots it will find the ESP - efi system partition and add the Windows 8 entry back into UEFI or not. You can always use efibootmgr from a Ubuntu live installer flash drive to add a Windows UEFI boot entry if required.

Comment: @oldfred I'm not familiar with these technicalities (actually, I don't even know what exactly UEFI is). Could you elaborate your explanation a bit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will be too much info for you now, but at bottom is a list of terms and links with further explanation. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295 Also has links to many useful UEFI instructions.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks, I'll have a look at it. But could you tell me in a few words if I need to do anything in particular when installing Xubuntu on the new drive and if I'll be able to put hdd1 back and use Windows normally after?

Comment: @oldfred Also,  when you say "you can always use efibootmgr from a Ubuntu live installer flash drive to add a Windows UEFI boot entry if required", do you mean that, when I may want to switch drives again, I just have to put hdd1 back and use this command to repristinate things as they were?

Comment: Yes, drive should just work again. But UEFI has its own memory of UEFI entries. And it seems to then lose those when drive is disconnected. I think UEFI normally (but maybe not all systems) find new entries when booting, so a normal boot (not UEFI fast boot) should find entries. May take a couple of tries. And using Ubuntu live installer you can easily add an entry to boot Windows if it does not auto find it.  I would use gpt & UEFI boot with new drive. See link I posted as it has all the info or links to all the info you need.

Comment: @oldfred The links and the explanations you provided were very useful:  I'm done and everything works fine.  Thanks!

Comment: To cope with EFIs "forgetting" boot entries, you can always install a boot manager as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the EFI System Partition (ESP; where boot loaders live on EFI computers). Something like my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) should work well for this, since it actively scans for boot loaders and presents a menu of options when it starts. See the [rEFInd installation instructions,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) and especially the [Alternative Naming Options](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming) section, for details of how to do this.